# Python how to convert character to string

Tags: python, string

```
array = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"

m = len(array)
user_input= input("Enter plaintext: ")
a= int(input("choose a: "))
b= int(input("choose b: "))

encryption = ""
for n in array:

   if n in user_input :
    
    inin=array.find(n)
    result =array.index(user_input) * a+b
    enc= result % m
    encryption = encryption + array[enc]
    
    
    
    
   
 print("Encrypted message is :"+encryption)
```

as you can see from the code above my code worked fine but the only problem that I am facing is
I need to encrypt the message as string like I want to use " hello world" not only a character "s" and its encrypted to " d" i want "hello word"

Comment: Please put the code directly in the question. Screenshots of code don't help us to help you.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include your code as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: Python doesn't really have a concept of "characters" as separate from "strings". Characters are just strings of length 1. Can you show us your desired output and explain how it differs from the current behaviour?

Comment: Characters are strings. Python does not have a separate character type. Also, use spaces for indentation, and when you ask questions on Stack Overflow, include your code as text, not a screenshot. Please see [tour] and [ask] for details.

Comment: Anyway, the reason your code doesn't work for longer inputs is that your program's logic doesn't make any sense. Try iterating over the `user_input` and checking if each character is in the `array`, instead of the other way around. You should also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to *read* the error messages you are given. For example, this program will tell you "substring not found", and points at the line that does `array.index(user_input)`. So, clearly, it means that `user_input` isn't a substring of `array`.

Comment: I'd recommend a [mcve] where you set the plaintext as a literal string, and don't ask for any input. Just show one specific input (the plaintext), actual ciphertext and expected ciphertext. But first you'll need to debug your code to actually run, then we can talk flaws in your algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to correct your code:

```py
array = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"

m = len(array)
user_input= input("Enter plaintext: ")
a= int(input("choose a: "))
b= int(input("choose b: "))

encryption = ""
for char in user_input:
   if char in array :
    index = (array.find(char) * a + b) % m
    encryption += array[index]
   else:
    encryption += char

print("Encrypted message is :", encryption)
```

From what I understood, you are trying to encrypt your message by shifting the index using an affine function (and applying a modulo so it "loops" if the index is bigger than your alphabet size). Since your input can contain multiple times the same char, you need to iterate through *the input* and then check for the index of every char in your alphabet (array). Then you can apply your formula to the index and get the new char. I also added a code to add the unciphered char if it doesn't exist in your array. This will prevent you to lose informations when ciphering.
e.g.: `hello world` will be ciphered in `xirrm tmars` instead of `xirrmtmars` which couldn't be unciphered to get the original.